# Getting Website Data From Running Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I understand that a `Service` class runs in the background in Android and I also understand how to `start` and `stop` a service.

I am just trying to get a better idea of how to use a `Service`.

So say I have a service running in the background, how would I print the URL name of a webpage in my service when I navigate to a random website using Chrome, Firefox, Samsung Internet, etc.

Here is my service below:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

private static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;
private static final String NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_Id";

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // do your jobs here

    startForeground();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void startForeground() {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    startForeground(NOTIF_ID, new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,
            NOTIF_CHANNEL_ID) // Create a Notification Channel
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.runningtitle))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.runningtext))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build());
  }
}
```

Comment: Each app runs in its separate process. Unless those browsers expose current url data to the system with something like a broadcast (which they don't) it's undoable.

Comment: @Pawel So I can't get any sort of website data from my app's running service?